# spaCy: errors attempting to load serialized Doc

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am trying to serialize/deserialize spaCy documents (setup is Windows 7, Anaconda) and am getting errors. I haven't been able to find any explanations. Here is a snippet of code and the error it generates:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
text = 'This is a test.'
doc = nlp(text)
fout = 'test.spacy' # <-- according to the API for Doc.to_disk(), this needs to be a directory (but for me, spaCy writes a file)
doc.to_disk(fout)
doc.from_disk(fout)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-7-aa22bf1b9689>", line 1, in <module>
    doc.from_disk(fout)

  File "doc.pyx", line 763, in spacy.tokens.doc.Doc.from_disk

  File "doc.pyx", line 806, in spacy.tokens.doc.Doc.from_bytes

ValueError: [E033] Cannot load into non-empty Doc of length 5.
```

I have also tried creating a new Doc object and loading from that, as shown in the example ("Example: Saving and loading a document") in the spaCy [docs](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#section-serialization), which results in a different error:

```
from spacy.tokens import Doc
from spacy.vocab import Vocab

new_doc = Doc(Vocab()).from_disk(fout)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-16-4d99a1199f43>", line 1, in <module>
    Doc(Vocab()).from_disk(fout)

  File "doc.pyx", line 763, in spacy.tokens.doc.Doc.from_disk

  File "doc.pyx", line 838, in spacy.tokens.doc.Doc.from_bytes

  File "stringsource", line 646, in View.MemoryView.memoryview_cwrapper

  File "stringsource", line 347, in View.MemoryView.memoryview.__cinit__

ValueError: buffer source array is read-only
```

**EDIT:**

As pointed out in the replies, the path provided should be a directory. However, the first code snippet creates a file. Changing this to a non-existing directory path doesn't help as spaCy still creates a file. Attempting to write to an existing directory causes an error too:

```
fout = 'data'

doc.to_disk(fout) Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-8-6c30638f4750>", line 1, in <module>
    doc.to_disk(fout)

  File "doc.pyx", line 749, in spacy.tokens.doc.Doc.to_disk

  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\pathlib.py", line 1161, in open
    opener=self._opener)

  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\pathlib.py", line 1015, in _opener
    return self._accessor.open(self, flags, mode)

  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\pathlib.py", line 387, in wrapped
    return strfunc(str(pathobj), *args)

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'data'
```

Python has no problem writing at this location via standard file operations (`open`/`read`/`write`).

Trying with a Path object yields the same results:

```
from pathlib import Path

import os

fout = Path(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'data'))

doc.to_disk(fout)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-17-6c30638f4750>", line 1, in <module>
    doc.to_disk(fout)

  File "doc.pyx", line 749, in spacy.tokens.doc.Doc.to_disk

  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\pathlib.py", line 1161, in open
    opener=self._opener)

  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\pathlib.py", line 1015, in _opener
    return self._accessor.open(self, flags, mode)

  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\pathlib.py", line 387, in wrapped
    return strfunc(str(pathobj), *args)

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Username\\workspace\\data'
```

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

```
doc.to_disk(fout)
```

must be

> a path to a directory, which will be created if it doesn't exist.
>   Paths may be either strings or Path-like objects.

as the documentation for spaCy states in https://spacy.io/api/doc

Try changing `fout` to a directory, it might do the trick.

EDIT:
Examples from the spacy documentation:

for `doc.to_disk`:

```
doc.to_disk('/path/to/doc')
```

and for `doc.from_disk`:

```
from spacy.tokens import Doc
from spacy.vocab import Vocab
doc = Doc(Vocab()).from_disk('/path/to/doc')
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out - I have updated my post accordingly - unfortunately I am still having issues. I should probably test on another machine. That said, contrary to what is stated in the docs, when I run this code spaCy writes a file instead of a directory.

Comment: @ongenz I see you're using anaconda and you got PermissionError. I had such a problem with conda on my linux machine. My solution was to delete conda and install and download everything manually; in my case, pip commands from the command line. I would suggest trying to run this code on a machine without anaconda - or try to delete anaconda on your current machine, it's up to you.

Comment: I tried running this on my Mac/Python 3.6/spaCy 2.012 and get the same errors. Are you able to run this code without errors?